# How many voles trapped until I give up?

Tags: pests, pest-control

I have a 5.5 acre lot backing up to a field where the farmer rotates corn/soy beans. Voles haven't been a problem until this year, but now they're taking over! The yard is now riddled with their holes and paths.

I've trapped (mouse traps) 14 voles so far in just under 2 days. Is this a pointless endeavor, or should I keep going with this method?  It's time-consuming to check, clear and reset the 64 traps I have out. If there are 1,000 voles out there, I have no chance, but if 100, maybe worth keep going?

Any thoughts, suggestions...etc welcome!

Comment: You need some copperheads. Apparently snakes and voles are in balance in my yard as I rarely see either

Comment: @blacksmith37 I agree! (snakes, not copperheads :)  We used to have 3-4 large fox snakes in the area, but they've gotten killed (mower, road, and neighbors), and now we have mice, voles...etc. I've been asking around for anyone who wants to relocate fox snakes (aka rat snakes), but no luck so far.

Answer (score 1):

Don't bother trapping.

If they have a solid food source from the fields behind then you don't stand a chance as an individual competing manually against rodent reproduction rates.

> Reproduction: As some of the most prolific breeders in the rodent family, voles can produce 5-10 litters per year with 3-6 young per litter. Voles reproduce throughout the entire year, with peak rates in the spring and summer. https://www.havahart.com/vole-facts

However you can get various vole repellants, usually castor oil based, that may help you keep them away.

Comment: Thanks. The traps are certainly trapping, but so far, no end in sight (to your point).